# Stored procedure to java attributes

Tags: java, stored-procedures, sybase

I have a bunch of Sybase SP's for CRUD operations that I need to create services for in the mid-tier layer.

All the SP's are in place but the mid-tier has to be built from scratch.

Is there an easy way or a tool that allows you to convert stored procedure parameters into java class attributes?

For example:

```
create proc insertEmployee( @id int, @floor int )
```

to

```
public class Employee{

private int id;
private int floor;
}
```

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such tool. You can write your own generator using database metadata info: `Connection.getMetadata()`